# How to Use NSData to Get Pictures in Swift

Tags: swift, https, nsdata

This is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "news", for: indexPath)
    let lebel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    let lebel1 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    lebel.text = self.titlename[indexPath.row]
    lebel1.text = self.content[indexPath.row]
    var image: UIImage?
    if let imageURL = URL(string:self.picture[indexPath.row] ) {
        do {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf:imageURL as URL)
            image = UIImage(data:imageData as Data)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
    if image != nil {
        cell.imageView?.image = image
    }else{
        cell.imageView?.image = nil 
        //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "failed") 
    }
    return cell
}
```

`self.picture` is a `String` array. When I make a network request, the URL I want to connect to is `https://localhost:8443/news/p0.jpg`. I get this error：

> 2017-01-11 10:11:28.888 pro[19800:2397129] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)error

But I have been using Alamofire to connect to https in other places has been very successful. What is wrong with it?

OK,I try to use `URL` and `Data`,But this has nothing to do with the error

Comment: You are using Swift. Don't use `NSData` or `NSURL`. Use `Data` and `URL`.

Comment: You sure it's not a problem with that URL? I just tried pasting it in my browser and I get an error even using that.

Comment: You are connection to "localhost". That's whatever device you are running the app on (your Mac if it's the simulator, or whatever iOS device if testing on a real device). Assuming you are using the simulator, does your Mac have a valid SSL cert for the web server running on port 8443?

Comment: of course! I can get json strings from this address. And I can open this picture from safari on port 8443.

Answer (score 0):

OK,it is done! because I use `Alamofire` to manager the connection, so I must use alamofire to fetch the image data. Rather than the original method!!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "news", for: indexPath)
    let lebel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    let lebel1 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let pict = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView
    lebel.text = self.titlename[indexPath.row]
    lebel1.text = self.content[indexPath.row]
    if let imageURL = URL(string:self.picture[indexPath.row]) {
        Alamofire.request(imageURL, method: .get).responseData { response in
            guard let data = response.result.value else {
                pict.image = nil
                //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "failed")
                return
            }
            pict.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

But so much thanks!